# Is it true that $[T^{-1}(T(A))]^c=T^{-1}(T(A)^c)$?

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $X,Y$ be two vector space, $A\subset X$. Let $T:X\rightarrow Y$.

Is it true that $[T^{-1}(T(A))]^c=T^{-1}(T(A)^c)$?

**My attempt:**

$\subseteq:\ $Let $x\in [T^{-1}(T(A))]^c$.

Then, $x\notin T^{-1}(T(A))\Rightarrow T(x)\notin T(A)\Rightarrow T(x)\in T(A)^c\Rightarrow x\in T^{-1}(T(A)^c)$

Therefore, $[T^{-1}(T(A))]^c\subseteq T^{-1}(T(A)^c)$

Is the inclusion $\subseteq$ ok? Any hint for the other inclusion?

Comment: Your question shows your effort, so why did you delete it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that\begin{align}x\in\left(T^{-1}\bigl(T(A)\bigr)\right)^\complement&\iff x\notin T^{-1}\bigl(T(A)\bigr)\\&\iff T(x)\notin T(A)\\&\iff T(x)\in\bigl(T(A)\bigr)^\complement\\&\iff x\in T^{-1}\left(\bigl(T(A)\bigr)^\complement\right).\end{align}The linearity of $T$ is not relevant.

Comment: Thanks, all clear now.